# How to convert ( 11011.0101 ) from binary to decimal?

Tags: digital-logic, binary

How do we convert this binary number to decimal? I am confused about the decimal point, the one before the decimal I got (27), how about the part after the decimal point?

Comment: Context is required. What is the number supposed to represent?

Comment: <pedantry>It's not a 'decimal point' if the number is binary- you can call it a [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point).</pedantry>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the expansion is performed like this:

$$1\times2^4+1\times2^3+0\times2^2+1\times2^1+1\times2^0+0\times2^{-1}+1\times2^{-2}+0\times2^{-3}+1\times2^{-4}$$

This is analogous to the usual base-10 positional representation except the 10s are replaced with 2s.

Answer (score 4):

The positions to the right of the point are treated the same way as the ones before: each step to the right *halves* the weight. Hence

```
binary   | decimal
------------------
100.     |    4
 10.     |    2
  1.     |    1
  0.1    |  1/2
  0.01   |  1/4
  0.001  |  1/8
```

With these weights you should be able to calculate the decimal value of any binary number, including ones like you show with a .

Comment: +1, all the answers say essentially the same thing (they have to) but this one says it most clearly

Comment: @Neil_UK Wouter is a teacher, after all. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The place values go with \$2^n\$, where \$n\$ is positive on the left side of the decimal point and negative on the right side of the decimal point.

In this case,

```
         1   1   0   1   1  .  0      1      0      1
power    4   3   2   1   0    -1     -2     -3     -4
value   16   8   4   2   1     0.5    0.25   0.125  0.0625
```

Result: 27.3125

Answer (score 0):

Split it in 2 parts:
 a) 11011 which is 1 + 2 + 8 + 16 = 27
 b) 0101 which would be converted this way:

```
 0 * 1/2 + 1 * 1/4 + 0 * 1/8 + 1 * 1/16 = 5/16 = 0.3125
```

Number in decimal is 27.3125

you can check the following link for more examples
[Floating To Decimal](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/ftod.html)

Comment: How did you get 27.9375?

Comment: @alex.forencich typo! sorry